# Submit Form Response to SharePoint List isn't updating SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I'm built a simple Microsoft flow that is taking responses from a form and places the responses into a SharePoint library.

Trigger: When new response submitted (forms trigger) - this is set to the form

Action: Get response details - Form Id = Form, Response Id = 1

Action: Create an item (SharePoint) - site address = test site, list name test list name and then all the fields are mapped.

When I test the flow I get all green checkmarks, but then there is nothing in the SharePoint library.

The only thing I question is the Response Id.  I set it to 1, but I don't know if that is correct.  (It was recommended by a blog w/out any explanation)

There is some mention of this feature not working, but being resolved by Microsoft.   I'm not seeing any errors with the flow,  when I do a test run it runs correctly and no errors.  Can anyone help with me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Trigger When a new response is submitted

then box the rest in Apply to each

List of response
get response details
SharePoint Create item

[image]